# What is the maximum length for keyword type in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) is documentation about keywords but they haven't tell any limits. The fault lenght as I spot is 256 characters but how to get maximum length for keyword datatype?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The maximum bytes can be at most 32766. You will get a following error reason when the bytes go beyond 32766.

```
"reason": "Document contains at least one immense term in field=\"tags\" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[82, 83, 75, 66, 99, 81, 87, 70, 69, 72, 49, 65, 70, 71, 48, 48, 53, 101, 86, 54, 112, 67, 53, 54, 80, 112, 56, 54, 70, 72]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 32770",
"caused_by": {
  "type": "max_bytes_length_exceeded_exception",
  "reason": "bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 32770"
}
```